# How to fix mysql select command giving wrong result after the update in another db connection?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, innodb, mysql-select-db

I have taken two mysql db connections using python MySQLdb module namely `db` and `db1`. The first connection is used to read a table and the second connection is for updating the table. 
The following are the sequence of code that I have used.

1 : Read id from user table using `db` conncetion; current value 'Y'

2 : Update id in user table to 'N' using `db1` connection.

3 : Reading id from user table using `db` connection. But at this time it gives value 'Y'.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","test007","db",charset='')

apikey="123"


cursor=db.cursor()                                             ## fetching no. of data received in valid time range
cursor.execute("select id from USER where apikey=%s",(apikey,))
data=cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
print data #current value 'Y'

db1 = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","test007","db",charset='')

cursor=db1.cursor()                                             ## fetching no. of data received in valid time range
cursor.execute("update USER set id='N' where apikey=%s",(apikey,))
db1.commit()
cursor.close()
db1.close()

cursor=db.cursor()                                             ## fetching no. of data received in valid time range
cursor.execute("select id from USER where apikey=%s",(apikey,))
data=cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
print data
db.close()
```

In step 3 it doesn't show the updated value. Why does this happen? How can i solve this issue without closing the connection `db` and take another connection to read the table after update?

This is not the actual code implementation. db1 is actually running from some other file. For simplicity, I just showed this.

Comment: What is the setting of `autocommit`?  Do you use transactions?

Comment: I haven't used autocommit. If you run the above code, it will have the above said problem.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%isoloation%';`

Comment: When to check this variable? after running the file ?

Comment: Any time.  It is a setting that won't change unless you deliberately change it.  (And it sounds like you are not changing it.)

Comment: It gives the result `REPEATABLE-READ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing what it is supposed to.  `REPEATABLE-READ` means that you see the same data, regardless of what is going on in other transactions.  This, of course, lasts only until your transaction terminates.

Think of it as taking a snapshot of the entire dataset when you start the transaction.  Then, everything you do or see (`SELECT`) is frozen in time.

Either change to `READ-UNCOMMITTED` or break up the `SELECTs` into separate transactions.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, this is apparently as it ought to behave because of this illustion below (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)
[image]

So simply commiting transaction before reading from the session resolves this error.